# BindingComplete on BindingSource not called

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox and a DataSource for it:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsContractors;
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbContract_Contractors;        

bsContractors = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
bsContractors.DataSource = typeof(Contractor);
bsContractors.BindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.BindingCompleteEventHandler(this.bsBindingComplete);

cmbContract_Contractors.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.bsProject, "ContractorId", true));
cmbContract_Contractors.DataSource = this.bsContractors;
```

I see the data in the ComboBox, but the BindingComplete method is never called.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding event handler earlier in code.

Comment: That code is in the Designer. I don't think I have that kind of control.

Comment: maybe this can hep https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/67f2d0a1-ff04-455d-b217-c327e05ab7e4/bindingcomplete-event-isnt-firing-why?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this block of code might work. I added comment '//changed' to changes. I used info from @GuidoG comment

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsContractors;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbContract_Contractors;

        bsContractors = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        bsContractors.DataSource = typeof(Contractor);
        bsContractors.BindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.BindingCompleteEventHandler(this.bsBindingComplete);

        var binding = new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.bsProject, "ContractorId", true);  //changed
        binding.FormattingEnabled = true;   //changed
        cmbContract_Contractors.DataBindings.Add(binding);  //changed
        cmbContract_Contractors.DataSource = this.bsContractors;
```